Compensation for cancellation on multi-leg trip to Germany via LHR
Am I eligible for a compensation under the following circumstances? If yes, which amount?
Route:
LAX - LHR - HAM
Booked with British Airways as one booking
LAX - LHR => codeshare flight operated by American Airlines
LHR - HAM operated by BA, cancelled because someone deleted the flight in their system an no passenger list were available for boarding. Hotel and transfer was provided. Booking on same aircraft with different flight number for the next day. Arrived in Hamburg with 17h delay.
Additionally here more details:

LAX - LHR BA1613 operated by AA Sept. 5th was on time
LHR - HAM BA972 operated by BA Sept. 6th cancelled due to circumstances mentioned above
LHR - HAM BA970 Sept. 7th, arrived in HAM with 17h delay compared to the planned arrival of the whole trip


Please do not just use airport codes, one letter wrong gives a completely different airport sometimes in a different country.

Yes, you are entitled to compensation since the flight was marketed and operated by a UK carrier originating from the UK. The tricky part here is that the compensation is dependent on "distance". BA is likely to claim that only the distance LHR to HAM matters. The law is written quite poorly and lacks a lot of details, this being one of them. That means, all the details get decided by the courts. In this case, there is a clear ruling in the EU that distance means the entire itinerary (https://curia.europa.eu/juris/liste.jsf?num=C-559/16). I'm not sure about the UK though.

You are covered by the UK261, which is almost a copy paste of EU261. I think you should be compensated in the situation you described:

Delay must be at least 3 hours long, and it must be the airline’s
fault.
For example, technical problems are airline’s fault.


The CAA’s website is probably a better reference.
